# Full clear or fully clear

Tags: word-choice

I was describing the weather conditions. I used the following sentence:

> The clouds were floated away by the wind.**It was a fully clear sky.**

I checked this sentence on Grammarly, which suggested me that this sentence should be:

> The clouds were floated away by the wind. **It was a full clear sky.**

I think **"fully"** is more appropriate here, as it shows a degree of completeness. Since sky can be partially clear as well. Need suggestion for the suitable sentence out of two aforementioned ones.

Comment: I am a bit confused what a "full (or fully) clear sky" is? Usually we focus on the clouds - *cloudy* or *partly cloudy*. And *clear* means no clouds.

Comment: Clear is clear. There is no need to add an adjective. It is superfluous.

Comment: Oh, I don't know. You can also say "mostly clear" to imply there aren't many clouds, so why would "fully clear" be wrong?

Comment: @MrLister In case there aren't many clouds, 'mostly sunny'/'partly cloudy' is used. Mostly clear isn't a thing to describe weather in formal English in my opinion.